# AbstractAccountAuthenticator prompt login in refresh token when stored credential are no longer valid

Tags: android, authentication, oauth-2.0, refresh-token

I'm implementing the android account authenticator, so far I can add accounts get a token etc.
The problem is when I change credential server side.

As I can't get notified from the server if credentials changed, my next API request will be denied as the token is not longer valid.

After getting a request denied there could be 2 reasons for it -> token expired or credentials no longer valid

When this happen I invalidate the token saved and call getAuthToken()

In my getAuthToken() I first attempt a request for a new token, if it gets denied means that credential are not ok anymore so I need to prompt login activity.
The problem is AccountAuthenticatorResponse.onError seems only able to log the error and that's it.
I tried to use AccountAuthenticatorResponse.onResult passing the bundle with the KEY_INTENT for login activity but it does't do anything.
Any thoughts?

```
@Override
public Bundle getAuthToken(final AccountAuthenticatorResponse authenticatorResponse, final Account account,
                           final String authTokenType, Bundle bundle) throws NetworkErrorException {

    //Get the account manager to access the account details
    final AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(mContext);
    String authToken = accountManager.peekAuthToken(account, authTokenType);

    //If auth token is null then try to log in the user with the stored credentials
    //It could be that previous token has expired
    if (authToken == null) {
        final String password = accountManager.getPassword(account);
        final String clientID = accountManager.getUserData(account, CLIENT_ID_KEY);
        final String apiSecret = accountManager.getUserData(account, API_SECRET_KEY);
        final String serverUrl = accountManager.getUserData(account, SERVER_ADDRESS_KEY);

        if (password != null && clientID != null && apiSecret != null && serverUrl != null) {
            Logger.log(LOG_TAG, "Requesting new token...", Log.VERBOSE);
            ApiRequestManager.getInstance(mContext)
                    .getToken(serverUrl, clientID, apiSecret, account.name, password,
                            new NetworkCallBack() {
                                @Override
                                public void tokenReceived(Token JsonToken) {
                                    //Credentials still valid, token received
                                    //Returning data back to the account authenticator
                                    Bundle result = new Bundle();
                                    result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
                                    result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
                                    result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, JsonToken.getAccess_token());
                                    authenticatorResponse.onResult(result);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void errorReceivingToken(VolleyError errorResponse) {
                                    //If we are here with error 400 it only means credentials have changed
                                    //I should prompt LogIn activity at this point
                                    if (errorResponse.networkResponse.statusCode == 400) {
                                        Bundle loginActivityBundle =
                                                promptLoginActivity(authenticatorResponse, account.type, authTokenType, null);
```

//                                            authenticatorResponse.onResult(loginActivityBundle);
                                            authenticatorResponse.onError(errorResponse.networkResponse.statusCode, "error");

```
                                    }
                                }
                            });
            return null;
        }
    }

    //If we got an authToken return the account and login info in a bundle
    if (authToken != null) {
        Bundle result = new Bundle();
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, authToken);

        return result;
    }

    //If we are here then means either we do not have an account signed
    //or credentials are no longer valid -> prompt login procedure again
    return promptLoginActivity(authenticatorResponse, account.type, authTokenType, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
When I invoke getAuthToken() i pass an accountManagerCallback which receives either success or fail, from here I can prompt logIn if it was a fail due to auth exception.